# How do I suppress indentation after labels in Groovy?

Tags: indentation, cc-mode

I'm writing some Groovy code, and in my unit tests I have something like the following:

```groovy
def testFoo(){
    given:
    //setup statement 1
    //setup statement 2
    //...

    when:
    //Execute code

    then:
    //check results
}
```

The problem is that emacs, by default, autoindents so that the code looks like the following:

```groovy
def testFoo(){
    given:
        //setup statement 1
    //setup statement 2
    //...

    when:
        //Execute code
    //Execute code 2

    then:
        //check results
    //check results 2
}
```

That is to say, emacs is indenting the first statement underneath the label.

How do I prevent emacs from doing this? I've tried running `M-x c-set-offset <RET> label` and setting the indentation to both 0 and `-` to no avail. Which offset should I be customizing?

**EDIT**: More generally, how do I see which indent rule is in effect at the point?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a somewhat hacky solution by just disabling programmatic indentation for Groovy:

```
; Disable fancy indentation on Groovy-mode
(add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (setq indent-line-function 'indent-relative)))
```